# Generic paging algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, pagination

I have made a simple pagination algorithm. It shows "next" and "previous" buttons when appropriate.

It also limits the amount of buttons if the page amount exceeds a certain amount, e.g. `1 2 ... 15 16 17 18 19 ... 99 100`.

It works fine, but I feel it can be simplified.

```js
function appendTruncateButtons(buttons, pageCount) {
  buttons.push("...");
  buttons.push(pageCount - 1);
  buttons.push(pageCount);
}

function prependTruncateButtons(buttons) {
  buttons.push(1);
  buttons.push(2);
  buttons.push("...");
}

function generateButtons(currentPage, pageCount, surroundingPageLinkSize) {
  var buttons = [];

  if (currentPage > 1) {
    buttons.push("<");
  }

  var truncate = pageCount > (7 + (surroundingPageLinkSize * 2));
  if (!truncate) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++) {
      buttons.push(i);
    }
  }
  else {
    var truncateEnd = currentPage < (1 + (surroundingPageLinkSize * 2)),
        truncateBoth = (pageCount - (surroundingPageLinkSize * 2)) > currentPage && currentPage > (surroundingPageLinkSize * 2);

    if (truncateEnd) {
      for (var j = 1; j < (4 + (surroundingPageLinkSize * 2)); j++) {
        buttons.push(j);
      }
      appendTruncateButtons(buttons, pageCount);
    }
    else if (truncateBoth) {
      prependTruncateButtons(buttons);
      for (var k = (currentPage - surroundingPageLinkSize); k <= (currentPage + surroundingPageLinkSize); k++) {
        buttons.push(k);
      }
      appendTruncateButtons(buttons, pageCount);
    }
    else { // Truncate start
      prependTruncateButtons(buttons);
      for (var l = pageCount - (2 + (surroundingPageLinkSize * 2)); l <= pageCount; l++) {
        buttons.push(l);
      }
    }
  }

  if (currentPage < pageCount) {
    buttons.push(">");
  }

  return buttons;
}
// generateButtons(currentPage, pageCount, surroundingPageLinkSize)
console.log(generateButtons(1, 100, 3));
console.log(generateButtons(50, 100, 3));
console.log(generateButtons(99, 100, 3));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>   var truncate = pageCount > (7 + (surroundingPageLinkSize * 2));
>   if (!truncate) {
>     for (var i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++) {
>       buttons.push(i);
>     }
>   }
>   else {
>     var truncateEnd = currentPage < (1 + (surroundingPageLinkSize * 2)),
>         truncateBoth = (pageCount - (surroundingPageLinkSize * 2)) > currentPage && currentPage > (surroundingPageLinkSize * 2);
>
>     if (truncateEnd) {
>       for (var j = 1; j < (4 + (surroundingPageLinkSize * 2)); j++) {
>         buttons.push(j);
>       }
>       appendTruncateButtons(buttons, pageCount);
>     }
>     else if (truncateBoth) {
>       prependTruncateButtons(buttons);
>       for (var k = (currentPage - surroundingPageLinkSize); k <= (currentPage + surroundingPageLinkSize); k++) {
>         buttons.push(k);
>       }
>       appendTruncateButtons(buttons, pageCount);
>     }
>     else { // Truncate start
>       prependTruncateButtons(buttons);
>       for (var l = pageCount - (2 + (surroundingPageLinkSize * 2)); l <= pageCount; l++) {
>         buttons.push(l);
>       }
>     }
>   }
> ```

Note that all of these cases have essentially the same `for` loop.

```
  var start = 1,
      end = pageCount;

  if (currentPage > surroundingPageLinkSize * 2) {
      start = currentPage - surroundingPageLinkSize;
      prependTruncateButtons(buttons);
  }

  if (currentPage < pageCount - surroundingPageLinkSize * 2 - 2) {
      end = currentPage + surroundingPageLinkSize;
  }

  for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
      buttons.push(i);
  }

  if (end < pageCount) {
      appendTruncateButtons(buttons);
  }
```

Now we call it just once, only changing the parameters.

We also only call the `prepend` and `append` methods once each.  You could even pull those into this method if you wanted, as they are no longer repeated code.

I also like that this gets rid of the three single use Boolean variables.  Since they weren't reused, they don't seem necessary.

I'm not sure if the output is an exact match for what you had originally, but it should give the same kind of display.

I didn't change it here, but consider changing `buttons` to `pages` or even `pageNumbers`.  These are the pages that you want to make links or buttons that go there.  But they aren't buttons yet.